# How to group mongo result for specific keys?

Tags: mongodb

I've a collection that has this documents:

```
{name: "x", code: 1},
{name: "x", code: 2},
{name: "x", code: 3},
{name: "x", code: 1}
```

How can i group and count the keys that **are equal to `1`** and what **is not equal** to `1`?
I manage to group by the `code` but the result comes separately for 1, 2 and 3

```
aggregate([
    {'$match': {'name': "x"}},
    {'$group': {'_id': '$code', 'total': {'$sum': 1}}},
    {'$sort': {'_id': 1}}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally sum the counter.

```
aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        key1: { // Count of all documents with keys(code) that are equal to 1
          '$sum': {
            '$cond': {
              if: { '$eq': [1, '$code'] },
              then: 1,
              else: 0
            }
          }
        },
        otherKeys: { // Count of all other documents with keys not equal to 1
          '$sum': {
            '$cond': {
              if: { '$eq': [1, '$code'] },
              then: 0,
              else: 1
            }
          }
        }
      },
    }
  ])
```

This would output a result document like this:

```
{ "_id" : null, "key1" : *, "otherKeys" : * }
```

Where `key1` is the count of all documents with keys equal to 1, while `otherKeys` is the count of all documents with keys not equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation with `$facet` allows you to query on same set of documents in multiple facets. You can the desired result with this query:

```
db.codes.aggregate( [
  { $project: { code: { $eq: [ '$code', 1 ] } } },
  { $facet: {
     code_is_1: [
          { $match: { code: true } },
          { $count: "Code equals 1" },
     ],
     code_not_1: [
          { $match: { code: false } },
          { $count: "Code not equals 1" },
     ],
  } },
  { $project: { Counts: { $concatArrays: [ "$code_is_1", "$code_not_1" ] } } },
] )
```

The result will look like this with the test documents you posted: `{ "Counts" : [ { "Code equals 1" : 2 }, { "Code not equals 1" : 2 } ] }`